# How to decrypt an encrypted image knowing the key but not much more on the algorithm?

Tags: python, aes, pycryptodome

I am downloading an image from my camera (Ezviz, model CS-BC1C) and this image is encrypted. I set the encryption key (a password) on the camera app (Android) so I know what the key is (I suppose, if the key and the password are the same thing). It looks like that the image is encrypted with AES 128 bit. That's pretty all I know...and I would like to decrypt it using python (or something else if needed).

Is it possible?

I think of making some loops to test different configurations that may have been used during the encryption. Something like the following (very simple, not working, example):

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from IPython.display import Image

key = b'my_key'

with open('encrypted_image_path',"rb") as f :
    data = f.read()

for mode in [AES.MODE_CFB,AES.MODE_EAX] :
    tmp = AES.new(key, mode=mode)
    clear_data = (tmp.decrypt(data))
    display(Image(data=clear_data))
```

As suggested by Ry, I checked is the encrypted files start with a common series:

```
for i in cims : #cims is a list of filenames of encrypted images 
    with open(rootpath+i,"rb") as f :
        data = f.read()
    if i == cims[0] :
        ref = data
    else :
        cmp = 0
        for d,r in zip(data,ref) :
            if d!=r :
                break
            cmp += 1
```

The result is that the first 704 characters are common. Here they are:

```
b'hikencodepictureda32f310f87cc50aeebd59bc51bbce39\xdc\xc1\xf6\x04\xd4\xc2\xe9j\x19[\x96\xee~rc`\xaf5\xc1\xa2"E<\xc2\x95I\x11\xd1\xd0c\xcd\xadq\xe9\x1e`,\xc8a\x13\xcb\xd8\xc9:,\x87\xc6a\x94H\xe7\x1d\x94G\xd5q\xfa(k\x01\xee\xd8\x17M>\xd5\xe1\x17\x9a\x1d\xb0\xa6\xb2ops\xe9\xe8#\xd0\xdc\x1b\x19\x86YBc\xe0[P\xa1\xdf\xear^\t\xc7\x99D\xc6;!\xe5\x9cB00h\x15\xc2\x16\xf5\x04\xac@C\xbb\x99\x97b\x9dbI\x1df3<&}9\x88\nH\xd1i\x04\x14>\x1c\x94\xd5\xd4\xa5\xe5\'\xe4N\xb4\x83\xb4~A\xb0\x8e;\xee}\xd53\xaf\xea>\x9a\xbeL\x92\x0e\x8bbQ\x13\xac\xc7\xc8(\x92v\xce\xb7\xdd\xa9v\xdfy\x13\xf3\xbdP3\xb3%\x99lO4\xcd\x8c\xd6W(\xdb\xca\x1d\xa9\xaf\x1b\xb8s0\xfb\x06\x1aX\xbc\xcb6\xad\x17nw\x00`H6j\xf4\xe0\x88\xdcM\x1a\x18\xf2\x97\xf8=t\xbf\xeb\xd7\x9b\x01<h\x855&\xe8\xe6\xfd\x1c3\xfd\xa1D\r\xca\xb9.~{\x10\xa3 \x15i\xbb\x06\xebo\xb0\xd4%\x9c|\x8e\x15vQ\xc4{\x8e\x1c\xcf\xe5\x19\xfa/\xa4\xf9\x84N\xc4\xdf\xca\xe6\'#!\x8b\x84\x85\xb5\xd5\xd9\x90\xda\x08\x8f{\x14J\xd0\xd6\x14\x04\x96\xfbQ\x96\xb3B2\xe2_\xdc\xb7}\x07\xf6\xd0+5@\xd2e\xbc\xdb\x15a5\xf4 \x17\x1cRI\xbc\xa5\x0f\xe2\x07ID\x08`\x1c\xda\xf2\xf5_;@l!\xbd\xaa\x8d\xb8\xf4m\xd5"E\'\xe0G&\xa0\x15\xa4\xf9X\xe0d\xf0\x1b\x80\xf7C\xb7z\x85~O4\xa0\xb2\x1c\x94\xd18 >\x08\xf9i\x01\xa7\xac}\xff\xf6\x7fHE\xbeJ\x81.\xf1\xdb:\x8f\xe8CN7\xb3\xb7\xe0Ke\xea\x83\x9f;\xd5PRZ\xcd\xc5nP\xd4\xfc\x19\xa0v\x14L_\xa0\x87\xe1\x14\x99\xbcC\xbc\xf4qb;\x02I\x0e\xfe|\x99|\xb7\xbb\x87\xa3\xeaD\xe9\xe3o\xfa\'\xc2\xaf\xf8M\x91\xae\xb2\xc2(Q\xe0NaN\xc9F$q\x98\x83B\xd9\xe2\xf6\x00\xb6\x82b\x88\x90\x84D^\'\x0etT\x15g~\xfd6/+&v%$\xde\x07{\x11\xbc\xac\xa7\xa0\xe6\xf8s\xee3\txj\x7fw%o\x84\xb6\x89\xb9\xb5\xbb\xdc\xce\xe8\xa4T@\xfcoC\xc7\xa9\xe8\xce-\xd0\x8b#wt\x05\x82DF\xadFu\xe2\xc8L\x13\xd2\x8e\xda\xb1\x12MV\x16t\xc4\xf1\xaa\xd4\x95\n\x08\xeb `\x01\x97\x88,\x9e\x0f1\x07J\xd3\x92\x1bWF\xb6.V\x07\xd1\xc4o\xa8\xcc\xceM\xbc\xc9\x0b8g\xbe\x1e\xec\xb5\x13\x9c\xe8h\xd0\xe8\xa6\x88\x9c\x91[\xd7~\xff\xd4%'
```

If I change the password in the app, only the first 16 characters (`b'hikencodepicture'`) remain commons with previously encrypted images.

As complementary information, the password that I can set-up in the app must have between 8 and 16 characters (numbers, special characters...). A max length of 16 corresponds to the length of the required key for AES 128 bit, isn't it?

Knowing that my knowledge on encryption is next to zero, if what I am looking for is not impossible, could someone help me with defining which combinations I should test to try to decrypt my image?

---

I also tested the following, with no success:

```py
key = getpass("Password:")
key = bytes(key,'utf-8')

iv = bytes.fromhex('da32f310f87cc50aeebd59bc51bbce39')

for d in [data,data[48:]] :
    for mode in modes_list :
        for i in [True, False] :
            try :
                if i :
                    tmp = AES.new(key, mode=mode, iv=iv)
                    print('iv')
                else :
                    tmp = AES.new(key, mode=mode)
            except (TypeError, ValueError) :
                continue
            clear_data = (tmp.decrypt(d))
            display(Image(data=clear_data))
```

Comment: Which camera? (Camera app?) Maybe even worse than how the encryption was applied and other details of the file format was how the password (is it a password? that’s what it sort of sounded like) was converted to a key. Also, a good place to start could be comparing two files using the same password. Do they start with the same bytes?

Comment: I edited the question to answer some of your questions. 
Concerning your proposal on the start of two files, what should I do is to compare the bytes (my `data` variable) of two images encrypted by the camera?

Comment: Thanks for adding the information. Yes, that’s right. On top of that, could you describe the key? Was it a password you chose, or something that the camera generated for you that you read off? (If the latter, what does it look like and how long is it?)

Comment: What I called `key` is a password that I personally chose (it is not generated by the camera). I have just compared the `data` issued from a bunch of encrypted images : the first 704 characters are common to all of them. Should I add this first part of characters to my question? Is there some confidential information in it?

Comment: It’s really impossible to say whether they contain confidential information without seeing them. If the images are competently encrypted, they shouldn’t, but who knows.

Comment: da32f310f87cc50aeebd59bc51bbce39 is 16 bytes as hex, so if you’re lucky (or unlucky because it means the encryption is bad), that’s some kind of hardcoded/key-derived IV, and the rest of it is encrypted data (with the common IV meaning there’s a long common image header encrypted the same way). The text/binary boundary would fit with that. At the same time, even if that *is* the case, figuring out how your password was turned into a key is hard. Was there a limit on the length of the password when you set it?

Comment: I added more information on the question. The password length is 16...which seems to correspond to the length of the key for AES 128 bit... am I wrong? It may be that the password is exactly the key (if the password is set to the maximum number of characters (i.e. 16)). But even in that case, I still do not know what/how I should test...

Comment: Try CBC mode (the most common mode), with `bytes.fromhex('da32f310f87cc50aeebd59bc51bbce39')` as the IV and your password (padded with 0 bytes at the end?) as the key.

Comment: For the password (as key) I will arrange myself to have 16 characters, not knowing how they fill the missing ones...